# Node Cron job to run on 28th and 29th day of every month

Tags: javascript, cron-task, node-cron

I want to run a cron job on every 28th and 29th day of a month. My code is as follows:

```
cron.schedule('* * 28,29 * *', function() {
  let d = Date()
  console.log(`*********************** Check Current Month's Data Cron Job - ${d} ************************`)
  othersController.checkCurrentMonthData()
})
```

Today is 28th Jan and this code is running every minute. How can I make it run only once on 28th and 29th of the month.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I am using node-cron. If I use '28,20 * *', at what time will it run?

Comment: i think problem because of `* * 28,29 * *`  starting two `*` it means run on every minute and hour of the date. you should mention minute and hour when you need to run cron for 28,29 dates. Like  `30 22 28,29 * *`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra: '0 0 28,29 * *' will work fine right? I believe it runs at 00:00 of 28th and 29th every month. Is this right?

Comment: yes, just print log and check it.